# My Gmail editor shows a strange right-click YALIG submenu

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, gmail

Using Windows 10, Chrome, standard Gmail (not G-Suite), when I right-click inside the Gmail editor, I get the following submenu. Clicking on the menu items doesn't seem to do anything. I haven't seen this submenu anywhere before.

[image]

Does anyone know what this is, or what it's for? I can't remember installing an extension called YALIG and if do a Google search for YALIG nothing comes up.

Using Chrome V90.0.4430.93.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YALIG actually stands for *Yet Another Lorem Ipsum Generator*. The exact extension you have installed is this one, [YALIG](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/yet-another-lorem-ipsum-g/fafiooicgpgnicbbkfgimcofbhpcledk?hl=en).

If you don't want it, just uninstall the extension.

Comment: Thanks! The acronym makes perfect sense now!